# Как редактировать дизайн темы "classima" elementor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Нужно видоизменить тему "classima". Есть некоторые элементы, которые я могу поменять в верстке, но никак не могу найти, где лежит файл с категориями. Сайт вроде на elementor-е сделан, не подскажете как можно менять дизайн сайта на elementor?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам нужно приобрести Elementor Pro, т.к. только там можно добавлять свой код. Потом вы можете

1. Зайти в редакцию любой страницы в Elementor
2. Нажать на меню Elementor

[image: 1]

3. Конструктор тем

[image: 2]
[image: 3]
Вуаля, там все что нужно